# PhpStorm changing unit test toolbar colors

Tags: themes, phpstorm

I'm using PhpStorm with Material Theme UI. All is good and nice, except the colors for different toolbars.

My particular case is related to the test results bar. When it fails, due to the color schema, I barely can read it. It currently looks like this:

[image: Screenshot]

Haven't been able to find any settings under `Editor` -> `Color schema`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Check under `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Color Scheme | Console Colors` -- it should be one of those there.

Comment: Just an addition: changing "ANSI Colors" (Red and, apparently, Gray) should help.